# SQL query to LinqToSql

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have this SQL query that I want to translate into Linq-to-SQL:

[image]

Now here's the beginning of the Linq-to-SQL code but I'm stuck on how to group fields and get SUM :

```
private void GetDatas()
{
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        using (DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var query = from ent in dc.STK_ABC_ENT
                        join det in dc.STK_ABC_DET on ent.ENT_ID equals det.ENT_ID
                        join art in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES on ent.ART_CODE equals art.ART_CODE
                        where !ent.ENT_NUM_PAL.Contains("FDR_")
                              && ent.ENT_OUTDATE == null
                              && ent.ENT_PICKING == null 
                              && ent.ENT_DATE_ENT != d
                        // How to group here ?
                        // How to get SUM ??
        }
}
```

Comment: **PLEASE** post the query **as nicely formatted text**  - don't post screenshots of code here - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group x by ColumnName into z` to group a column.

When you want to group multiple columns you can use `group x by new { x.Column1, x.Column2 } into z`.

When you want to group multiple columns in multiple tables you can use `group new { x, y } by new { x.Column, y.Column } into z`.

With `Sum`, just call it in select with lamda expression.

Example:

```
var query = from ent in dc.STK_ABC_ENT
            join det in dc.STK_ABC_DET on ent.ENT_ID equals det.ENT_ID
            join art in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES on ent.ART_CODE equals art.ART_CODE
            where !ent.ENT_NUM_PAL.Contains("FDR_") && ent.ENT_OUTDATE == null
                  && ent.ENT_PICKING == null && ent.ENT_DATE_ENT != d
            group new { art, ent } by new {
                art.ART_CODE,
                ...,
                ent.ENT_DATE_ENT,
                ...
            } into grouped
            select new {
                ArtCode = grouped.Key.ART_CODE,
                SumPdsNet = grouped.Sum(x => x.DET_PNET),
                ...
            }
```

I hope it can work for you.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for ! just one more question : i'm trying to add a orderby statement between "join art in..." and "where !ent..." like : "orderby ent.ENT_DATE_ENT" but it doesn't sort my query.

Comment: Oh, you can try to add an order by between group and select like this `orderby grouped.Key.ART_LIBELLE1`. Hope it works :D

Comment: That's it ! thank very much for helping me , i really appreciate!